# Construct URL for Socrate dataset query where date is greater than a date

Tags: swift, soql, socrata

This question has been asked but not in the Swift context.  I have a Socrata dataset I am retrieving using an OS X Swift app with a query like this:

`https://data.cityofwestsacramento.org/resource/wdus-j2nt.json?$where=date_applied>=2016-05-01`

It appears the problem is the encoding of "$where=date_applied>=2016-05-01", and Socrata does not like the date portion encoded apparently.

Any ideas on how to construct the NSURL in Swift to pass this query correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution using the code in https://github.com/socrata/soda-swift. licenseTimeFrame is just the number of days to look back:

```
  let dateCuttoff = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -licenseTimeFrame,toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour, .Day, .Month, .Year]
    let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(unitFlags, fromDate: dateCuttoff!)
    let dateString = "\(components.year)" + "-" + "\(components.month)" + "-" + "\(components.day)"
    let query = "date_applied>'\(dateString)'"
    let sk = query.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())! as String
    let url = "https://data.cityofwestsacramento.org/resource/wdus-j2nt.json?$where=\(sk)"
    let urlToSend = NSURL(string: url)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: urlToSend!);
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("[myapikey]", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-App-Token")
    // Execute HTTP Request
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in }
    // do processing here of return data
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Sounds like you're all set then? Sorry I didn't see this one sooner.

Comment: Yes - that would do it for now